Non-empty list examples from "Functional Programming in Lean" produce error: unsolved goals
I've been working through the "Functional Programming in Lean" document and the Non-Empty Lists examples don't work for me.
The code:
def xs := [1]
theorem xs_not_empty : xs.length > 0 := by simp

based on the "Arrays and Indexing" section, results in:
smol.lean:2:40: error: unsolved goals
⊢ 0 < xs.length

I suspect that something has changed between release 4.1 (which "Functional Programming..." says it has been tested with) and 4.12, which is my installed version, but I can't find it.

Maybe the relevant change is that definitions are now by default irreducible and I'm pretty sure that this change was between 4.1 and 4.12. So you have to tell simp explicitly to unfold the definition of xs now.
def xs := [1]
theorem xs_not_empty : xs.length > 0 := by simp [xs]

works fine.

That did it. Thanks!

TL;DR
by simp may not work as expected if your Lean version >= 4.3.0. Use by decide or by simp (config := {decide := true}) instead in later sections of "Functional Programming in Lean".
What change
Basiclly, this is because the default behavior of simp has changed since one patch related to Lean4-4.3.0. Before the change, simp would try to call decide to close the goal. But decide may be expensive in some computational proofs. The Lean community changes it and ensures that the core libs do not rely on decide inside simp. You can find more detail in the PR.
About FP-in-Lean
The code examples in this book are verified with Lean 4.1.0. You can find some same issues posted in the repo of the book. There is one with comment of the author

Comments here are fine. But the book's CI will catch it when I do the next version bump, so please don't feel like you need to find everything by hand.

It seems that the author prefers to fix typos and damaged proofs in the next edition of this book. He advises readers to get the general idea, but not the details of the code. It's right for Lean beginners.
Other things about simp tatic
If you have experience on other proof assistant e.g. Coq. I think the similar tatics simpl and auto appears more powerful in Coq environment although I don't know the implementation details behind them. I haven't used Coq in a while.
